# Nginx rewrite certain port to subpath (nginx + uwsgi + django)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite, django, uwsgi

My goal is to rewrite everything under `http://localhost:8000` to `http://localhost/foo`

I followed every step mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426844/1105489), but still couldn't get it work.

Here's my settings:

urls.py (Django)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'home.view'),
    url(r'^foo$', 'foo.view'),
]
```

uwsgi.ini (uWSGI)

```
[uwsgi]

chdir           = /home/user/folder/project
wsgi-file       = /home/user/folder/project/iTrends/wsgi.py
home            = /home/user/.pyenv/versions/project
master          = true
processes       = 10
threads         = 5
socket          = /tmp/project.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
logto           = /tmp/project_uwsgi.log
http-websocket  = true
buffer-size     = 65535
```

nginx80.conf (nginx with port 80)

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name = _;

    location /test {
        rewrite ^/test/(.*)$ /$1 break;   
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8000;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

nginx8000.conf (nginx with port 8000)

```
server {
    listen      8000;
    server_name _; 
    charset     utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /static {
        alias /home/user/folder/project/static_all;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  unix:///tmp/project.sock;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

Now
`http://localhost/test` is equivalent to `http://localhost:8000`

but when I go to `http://localhost/test/foo`, nginx tells me "not found"
(I expect this the same as `http://localhost:8000/foo`)

What did I miss?

Comment: Old question, but stumbled over it: I think proxy_pass is never reached because the rewrite is done before.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is the extra $ in the rewrite rule (in the first argument). I removed it and it has started working fine.

```
    location /test {
        rewrite ^/test/(.*) /$1 break;   
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8000;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Comment: I just include the location part, but  the rest is just the same as yours

Comment: Can you please post the full configuration block you are using?

Comment: No problem, I've updated my question.

Comment: Updated the answer; Seems the extra $ was the cause of your troubles; I tested it locally with the above configuration

Comment: Still not working, the problem might be uwsgi instead of nginx...

Comment: Try setting the error_log level to debug. You might get additional insights there. With the above configuration, I can confirm that I was able to get nginx redirection (or rather proxy) work